# UWP responsive: MultiColumn listview on landscape

Tags: listview, responsive-design, windows-10, multiple-columns, uwp

i'm writing an application showing a listview with Hotspots in a list, and i would like the list to show it's data in multiple columns if the window is wide (Win10) or the phone is in landscape (WP)
the only thing i can find on the internet is for HTML5 pages or for showing different data in different columns, but not to devide the data over 2 columns

this is the code i currently have:

```
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModelLocator}, Path=HotspotViewListViewModel }">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PageLoadedCommand}"/>
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <TextBlock Text="ListView" FontSize="32" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="123,0,122,580" />

    <ListView Name="HotspotList" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Hotspots}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedHotspot}" 
              Margin="10,60,10,10"
              >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340" >
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Square44x44Logo.png"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Location}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="275"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,25,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Street}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,25,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding City, Converter={StaticResource cityConverter} }" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding EditHotspotCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=HotspotList, Path=SelectedItem}" />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

    </ListView>


</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well apparently i'm stupid, the only thing i had to do was to change the ListView into a GridView